# How can I create ui like that in android studio?

Tags: android, user-interface

Hi Dear Android Developer  I hope all of you enjoying weekend very well I am developing cv Android app I recently come across UI screenshot below how can I achieve that such kinda UI in my layout**.

[image: ui like below]

below my XML layout where I have implemented my UI screenshot

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
                android:src="@drawable/education_information" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/education_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/education_info" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text_duration" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/institution"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text_institution"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/degree"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/text_degree"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

below my screenshot from real device
[image: update screenshot]

Comment: Using a relative layout will be easier in your case

Comment: Also show a screenshot on how your current layout looks

Comment: @VivekMishra can you clarify your answer

Comment: For more clarification first show how is the layout being created with the code that you have posted.

Comment: @VivekMishra, I have posted please check it

Comment: You can't create the desired ui using just a single linear layout. You have to use 4 linear layouts for your desired results

Comment: okay can you give me code sample

Comment: As I said before, it would be easier to use relative layout for your task. So if you don't know how relative layout works, I would advise is to study a bit about it then give it a try yourself. If you face any issue, you can ask here

Comment: @VivekMishraI I cant do it myself thats why I asked help

Comment: I think they are using paddingRight and and and padding Bottom on imageView

Comment: better to use margin than padding for imageview.

Comment: can you give some sample please I have tried myself I cant figureout please

Comment: I am not going to write the code for it. I can only describe steps to create it. First take a linear layout with vertical orientation. Next inside it create another linear layout with horizontal orientation. This layout will have your image and the Education text. This should help you to get going.

Comment: @VivekMishra can you guide me if I am stuck

Comment: Yes but atleast try what I told you to do

Comment: @VivekMishra, I have done as you told me what is the next step regards Yodgorbek

Comment: @VivekMishra, Please check my code as well

Comment: don't use match parent for the first layout. Keep it wrap content.

Comment: @Vivek Meshra what is the next step

Comment: @VivekMishra, I have done as you told me

Comment: Now simply add the remaining elements in the parent vertical layout. If you want to keep the years as a different element, then keep them in a separate horizontal layout.

Comment: @VivekMishra can you see updated screenshot how can I put textview I mean education text near to imageview like image above

Comment: make the imageview width wrap content and remove the margin right tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 *layout  for first image.*


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="120dp"
      android:background="@color/black_heading">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Education"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Education"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Education"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Education"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:textSize="10sp" />


       </LinearLayout>

  **Layout for second image**
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black_heading">
    </Toolbar>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="jhdfjkhjwqhfjhwqjfhwjqf"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="jhdfjkhjwqhfjhwqjfhwjqf"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="jhdfjkhjwqhfjhwqjfhwjqf"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

  inside on create view in your activity

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Litabswait Task");
```

Comment: I have used but I am getting output above can you review it thanks

Comment: I am getting weird output can you check it

Comment: What is please let me know

Comment: umesh shakya how can I increase size I mean can you see text showing properly